# My DiscordJSV13 Music Bot code has an error

Tags: discord.js

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DOQa.png)

This problem appears in my code every time I execute it. Is there any assistance I can get? Here's my music bot repository. https://github.com/iamZargo/MusicBot.git I'm hoping someone can assist me.

Comment: Please add your code and your error directly in the question as it would make the question more readable. Kindly refrain from using links and screenshots in the future

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are not passing any arguments named `arguments` to the command. When you run the command, you are just passing three arguments: `client, message, args` but in all of your commands, you are expecting four. So one way to fix your error would be to use the `args` argument instead of the `arguments` argument in each of your command like this:

```js
module.exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
    // ...
}
```

Another way would be to pass the fourth argument in your event handler so that all the commands would be able to use it. Something like this:

```js
let arguments = '' // Get all the arguments here
commandFile.run(client, message, args, arguments); // Then pass them into the command here
```

(Note: You already seem to be passing an `args` argument so why would you even need the fourth one?)